# How to use ggplot2 to draw plot outline using theme option?

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am  trying to use `ggplot` to plot data in python. I use the following:

```
from ggplot import *
print ggplot(frame,aes('x','y',color='z'))+ \
geom_point(size=40)+ \
geom_path(size=3)+ \
theme_bw()+ \
theme(panel_border=element_rect(colour="black"))
```

Python recognizes `theme_bw()` but in this theme it does not display the axis line not the box outline for the plot. I attempted to use `panel_border` to do the same but I get:

> NameError: name 'element_rect' is not defined

How can I get a box outline for my plot?